# OBSOLETE - SOAPI-WATCH: A realtime service that notifies subscribers via Twitter when the API changes in any way

Tags: app, dev-tool, api-v1, obsolete

### Obsolete:

> **This app no longer works.  It uses a version of the API that was [decommissioned in May of 2014](https://stackapps.com/questions/1352/what-is-soapi-and-why-should-i-care).**
>
> Links and the domain are also long dead.

### SOAPI-WATCH

---

<sub>This post was one of the two that were listed regarding SOAPI.</sub>

<sub>For a full overview of the SOAPI ecosystem see [What is SOAPI and why should I care?](https://stackapps.com/questions/1352/what-is-soapi-and-why-should-i-care)</sub>

---

At four hour intervals, [**SOAPI-WATCH**](http://soapi.info/Services/Watch.aspx) parses the complete Stack Overflow API documentation and generates a complete object graph representing the API including all routes, parameters and return formats.

This object graph is then compared, in minute detail, to the last known changed version.

Summary information differences do not trigger a change condition.

If changes are detected, the version just parsed is persisted and marked as latest and a Twitter status update is sent to [**@SOAPIWATCH**](http://twitter.com/soapiwatch) with a timestamp and link to the [**SOAPI-DIFF**](http://soapi.info/Tools/Diff.aspx) page, where changes are easily noted.

To be notified of API changes, follow [**@SOAPIWATCH**](http://twitter.com/soapiwatch).

**Latest**

The latest API specification, according to SOAPI, can be obtained via GET or POST at [**http://soapi.info/rest/api**](http://soapi.info/rest/api).

The default format is a human friendly, but complete, text dump that may be used for diff'ing API versions.

Formats available

- http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=txt -
  a formatted textual representation suitable for information/differencing.
- http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=json -
  a direct JSON serialization of the parsed API object graph.
- http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=json&jsonp=foo  -
  a direct JSON serialization of the parsed API object graph with padding. Useful for consuming the SOAPI from JavaScript applications. See [SOAPI-EXPLORE](https://stackapps.com/questions/603/) and [SOAPI-PARAM-EXAM](https://stackapps.com/questions/710) for examples.
- http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=xml -
  a direct XML serialization of the parsed API object graph

Comment: How does the "email" part work? I don't use Twitter but I see your title says it can email notifications. I don't see that option on the page or in the question though. I can see that this is going to be a very useful application though, as I've already had one of my apps break because of a change.

Comment: @farseeker - still working on a compact diff format. When it is complete I will expose a sub/unsub endpoint on the soapi.info/rest endpoint. When the compact diff format is complete I will build both email and rss.  Right now I am concentrating on writing examples and docs for the c#/silverlight wrapper. All of this should be wrapped up by the end of the weekend.

Comment: @farseeker - and I actually never saw a use for twitter until now. it is actually a very low friction mechanism for notifications. I am sold on it for that purpose. as far as 'twitting' what i just saw or how i feel... not sure that my initial eval of ridiculous is not still valid. ;-)

Comment: @code, cool - thanks. I don't use twitter on the basis that if you can say it in < 160 characters, it probably doesn't deserve to be said...

Comment: @code poet - WRT the twitter updates, it'd be nice if you could detect when the only thing that's changed is the first line of the api ;) That would help eliminate most of the "false positive" tweets.

Comment: @Dave - Yeah, I noticed that last week and have not gotten around to it. will address it later today. thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @dave - removed the revision number from the comparison. unless i broke something else things should quiet down.

Comment: note that with 1.1 changes (/help is deprecated), this method may not work any more.

Answer (score 5):

This is a great idea. I would prefer updates via RSS.

Comment: ++ great idea - keep them coming. I am building the www service now.

Comment: What kind of data would you expect to see in an rss feed concerning api changes?

Comment: I like your idea of a diff just listing the items that have been changed. I am not too particular about the format of the diff I just want to know when things are changed.

Comment: sorry, you are not amongst the 5 users to receive the first real notification from SOAPI-WATCH. ;-)  check the diff http://skysanders.net/soapi/watch/diff

Comment: I am working on a compact diff format right now. will post to soapiwatch when finished

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mind twitter updates.  That'd be quite useful.

Comment: http://twitter.com/SOAPIWATCH

Comment: congratulations, you are amongst the 5 users to receive the first real notification from SOAPI-WATCH! lol.

Comment: @code poet thanks! having these updates has been incredibly useful!