# OBSOLETE - SOAPI-PARAM-EXAM: A flat sortable, filterable list of all parameters in the Stack Overflow api

Tags: app, obsolete, dev-tool

> ## OBSOLETE: the soapi.info website is down

### SOAPI-PARAM-EXAM

[SOAPI-PARAM-EXAM](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/soapi-param-exam.htm) is a little scooby snack of a tool that lets you get your eyes on all of the parameters in the api.

This is useful for visually identifying inconsistencies in the api.

It is also an example of leveraging the SOAPI meta data endpoint.

[image]

### Location

You can view soapi-param-exam [here](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/soapi-param-exam.htm), or simply save the source code below to an .html document.

**Full Source Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * { font-family: 'Trebuchet MS' , 'Liberation Sans' , 'DejaVu Sans' ,sans-serif; }
        .dataTables_wrapper { position: relative; min-height: 302px; clear: both; _height: 302px; zoom: 1; /* Feeling sorry for IE */ }
        .dataTables_length { width: 40%; float: left; }
        .dataTables_filter { width: 50%; float: right; text-align: right; }
        table.display { margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; clear: both; }
        table.display thead th { padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; *cursor:hand;}
        table.display tfoot th { padding: 3px 10px; border-top: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; }
        table.display tr.heading2 td { border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa; }
        table.display td { padding: 3px 10px; }
        table.display td.center { text-align: center; }
        tr.odd { background-color: #E2E4FF; }
        tr.even { background-color: white; }
        .clear { clear: both; }
        .dataTables_empty { text-align: center; }
        table.display tr.even.row_selected td { background-color: #B0BED9; }
        table.display tr.odd.row_selected td { background-color: #9FAFD1; }
        table.display td { font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono WT" , "Andale Mono" , "Lucida Console" , "Lucida Sans Typewriter" , "DejaVu Sans Mono" , "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono" , "Liberation Mono" , "Nimbus Mono L" , Monaco, "Courier New" , Courier, monospace; font-size: 11px; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON("http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=json&jsonp=?", function(data) {
                var aDataSet = [];
                $(data.Routes).each(function(idx, route) {
                    $(route.Parameters).each(function(idx, param) {
                        aDataSet.push([route.Path, param.Name, param.TypeDescription,
                        param.Optional.toString(), param.Summary]);
                    });
                });
                $('#grid').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "aaData": aDataSet,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "sTitle": "Route" },
                        { "sTitle": "Name" },
                        { "sTitle": "TypeDescription" },
                        { "sTitle": "Optional" },
                        { "sTitle": "Summary" }
                    ]
                });
            }, function(data) { alert(data.message); });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        SOAPI-PARAM-EXAM</h3>
    <p>
        A sortable, filterable list of all parameters in the Stack Overflow api</p>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="grid">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```