# Is there an RSS feed or question that has API changes?

Tags: feature-request, api, documentation, rss

Is there someplace that we can find notifications of API changes?  I noticed today that a new property has been added to user along with a couple new method (and maybe other changes).

Is there an RSS feed or similar notification system to let us know when and what changed in the API?  Because of the way I wrote my library, it broke with the new updates.
I can (and a good chance is that I will) change the way my API works, but it would be nice to know when changes happen, because I don't think checking the documentation daily is a good method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you just looking for code poet's: [OBSOLETE - SOAPI-WATCH: A realtime service that notifies subscribers via Twitter when the API changes in any way](https://stackapps.com/questions/534/obsolete-soapi-watch-a-realtime-service-that-notifies-subscribers-via-twitter)
(Now obsolete)